# ¿A qué se debe el error en el manejo de punteros en C?

Tags: c, punteros

estoy trabajando arreglos con punteros pero al correrlo me muestra esos errores ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las funciones las declaro así:

```
void llenarArreglo(int *numero, int *arreglo){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < Tamanio; ++i) {
        *numero = rand()%9+1;
        *(arreglo+i) = *numero;
    }

}

void mostrarArreglo(int* arreglo){
    for (int i = 0; i < Tamanio; ++i) {
        printf("%i%s", *(arreglo+i)," ");
    }
}
```

Y las estoy mandando a llamar de la siguiente forma:

```
llenarArreglo(&numero, &arreglo);
mostrarArreglo(&arreglo);
```

Comment: Faltaría indicar la declaración de las variables `numero` y `arreglo`

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los errores? No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente tu `arreglo` sea una formación de veinte elementos:

```
int arreglo[20];
```

El tipo de una formación de enteros de veinte elementos es `int[20]`, por lo que un puntero a ese tipo (que es lo que pides mediante `&arreglo`) es de tipo `int(*)[20]`.

El tipo `int(*)[20]` no es `int *`, de ahí que el compilador te avise de la incompatibilidad de tipos, quita el operador de obtener la dirección (el et `&`) en la llamada a función:

```
llenarArreglo(&numero, arreglo);
//                     ^ <--- sin &
mostrarArreglo(arreglo);
//             ^ <--- sin &
```

Las formaciones son implícitamente convertibles a un puntero a su primer elemento, así que una formación de enteros (`arreglo[20]`) es implícitamente convertible a un puntero a entero (`int *`).